# Using XMLHttpRequest to Access XML File

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

I am currently having a problem with pulling information from an XML file of mine. Here is the relevant code.

```
var name = null;

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200) {
  myFunction(xhttp);
  }
};

xhttp.open("GET", "NAME.xml", true);
xhttp.send();

function myFunction(xml) {
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("uName")[0];
  var y = x.childNodes[0];
  name = y.nodeValue;
}

$.ajax({
  // Instructions to connect to requested XML file requested by user
  type: "GET",
  url: name,
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(xml){

  // ...
```

I am trying to pull the name of an XML file from another XML file. The code works fine if instead of using *name* in the `url` field I use the actual name of the desired XML file. However I am having trouble using a variable in this `url` space. I understand that `XMLHttpRequest` is asynchronous and that the code above pulls the *name* variable with a value of null. What is the best way to order the code so that I can successfully pull the name from `NAME.xml`. It may be useful to know that the XML files and the code are all in the same site root of a NetBeans project. Is there something obvious I am missing?

Comment: Xmlhttprequest is asynchronous. $.ajax will be called before myFunction gets called. Interesting mix of native xmlhttprequest and jquery.ajax.

Comment: Just place your `$.ajax({` inside `myFunction()`